# how to convert HH:MM:SS to H:SS AM/PM from SQL database with TIME_FORMAT

Tags: php, mysql, time

This is the working version of the query.  I only needed to save the new value with AS.Thank You to Andy.

```
$Wednesday = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *,TIME_FORMAT(class_start,'%l:%i %p') AS new_class_start,TIME_FORMAT(class_end,'%l:%i %p') AS new_class_end
FROM wednesday INNER JOIN classes_new ON wednesday.classes_id=classes_new.classes_id WHERE classes_status='0' AND class_start NOT LIKE ''ORDER BY class_start;");
```

I have a table with two datatype TIME columns when I run the query below the time value is returned as hh:mm:ss . I would like to convert it to h:mm AMPM. I have tried using javascript but I'm sure this is possible in MySQL. I have attempted  to use TIME_FORMAT but I think I am getting the wrong syntax.  After the below query is run the values are echoed in a while loop. Please Advise on the best way to convert the time values.
Thanks!

```
$Wednesday = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *,TIME_FORMAT(wednesday.class_start,'%h:%i %p')
```

FROM wednesday INNER JOIN classes_new ON wednesday.classes_id=classes_new.classes_id WHERE classes_status='0' AND class_start NOT LIKE ''ORDER BY class_start;");

Comment: WORKING VERSION OF QUERY:           $Wednesday = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *,TIME_FORMAT(class_start,'%l:%i %p') AS new_class_start,TIME_FORMAT(class_end,'%l:%i %p') AS new_class_end
FROM wednesday INNER JOIN classes_new ON wednesday.classes_id=classes_new.classes_id WHERE classes_status='0' AND class_start NOT LIKE ''ORDER BY class_start;");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
TIME_FORMAT(your_time,"%h:%i %p") AS your_time_formatted;
```

**EDIT!**
Added AS

Comment: I had attempted to use that function as such:  $Wednesday = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * DATE_FORMAT(your-date,"%h:%i %p")
FROM wednesday INNER JOIN classes_new ON wednesday.classes_id=classes_new.classes_id WHERE classes_status='0' AND class_start NOT LIKE ''ORDER BY class_start;");     but the query would not run may I ask where I went wrong?

Comment: See my edited answer, you should use TIME_FORMAT. But did you replaced "your-date" with the actual column name in your database? And you are also missing a comma sign in that query after SELECT *

Comment: yes I did replace it... Is the missing comma between * and TIME_FORMAT? if so i have corrected it

Comment: If it still does not work, there is something else wrong. Remove everything from your query and test only the TIME_FORMAT part against your time column

Comment: I have changed the original post to include the query as it currently exists. However I must still have an error in my syntax.

Comment: no error... but no results. when I remove the WHERE portion I get results but the time still is not formatted

Comment: 1. SELECT TIME_FORMAT("23:23:12", "%h:%i %p") Does it work? 2. SELECT TIME_FORMAT(wednesday.class_start, "%h:%i %p") FROM wednesday; Does it work?

Comment: No and No... I get a syntax error from DW when using "" around "%h:%i %p"... I had to use ' ' could this be the issue?